# How to get option name instead of option value from dropdown list in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, dropdownbox

I am using a dropdown list in JSP of spring MVC like this

```
<form:select path="isConfirmed">                                
        <form:option value="1">Yes</form:option>
        <form:option value="2">No</form:option>
</form:select>
```

when the user selects any option(e.g Yes) and click save button the corresponding value(e.g. 1) saved in database.Now in another JSP form I need to retrieve this user choice, but I am able to show only value(e.g. 1). But all I want to show option name like "Yes" in this case. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

a. The simplest way is to change the value of the option to the name in select:

```
<form:select path="isConfirmed">                                
        <form:option value="Yes">Yes</form:option>
        <form:option value="No">No</form:option>
</form:select>
```

In your case it's to change the value from `1,2` to `Yes,No`,then it can show in other JSP pages.

b. Don't modify the select code,instead you need to query the option detail (or calculate it)before you show another jsp page:

```
@RequestMapping("showAnotherPage")
public String anotherJSP(String value,Model model){
  SelecteMOdel sModel = modelService.findById(value);//query the detail infomation of selected value
  model.addAttribute("selectedModel",sModel);   
return "other.jsp";
}
```